# how to turn off analyzer in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I would like to know from where can I turn off the  analyzer in postgresql and what impact will it have on queries if they are plain simple queries (no joins nothing), simple group by , order by queries.

Comment: Why do you need that?  Sounds like a really bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

The auto_vacuum proces also does the analyzing of your data. You could turn it off.

Another option could be to set default_statistics_target to 0, but in both cases the queryplanner won't have any usefull information about how to execute a query. Most indexes won't be used and if an index is used, it could use the wrong one.

Turning of the analyzer, makes the queryplanner blind and stupid. Most of your queries will suffer.

Comment: @techieabhi In addition to the issues Frank mentions, if you try to turn of auto-analyze by turning autovaccum off entirely, you'll suffer from terrible table bloat, with lots of wasted disk space, slow index and table scans, and generally terrible performance. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Frank and Craig, we have to turn it off because we are facing lots of corruption issues as the postgres is shipped into a device and at customer end they switch off(power off the device) so postgres is not shutdown normally and this abrupt shutdown happens almost daily because of which we are facing huge corruption issues and we have found lots many times pg_statistics tables get corrupted, so if we turn the analyzer off we will atleast save that part of the corruption, as far as performance is concerned we have plain database tables.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't corrupt when you turn it off, unless your hardware isn't reliable. You'd better fix the real problems, instead of slowing down the database. On corrupted hardware, any table/database might get corrupted.